# Java Card 2.2.1 Application with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javacard

I want to develop an applet for Java Card 2.2.1 using Eclipse and SDK Java Card kit.

I am unable to set up Java Card 2.2.1 in Eclipse; It's okay when I use Java Card 2.2.2.

How can I set up Java card 2.2.1 in Eclipse?

Eclipse Version 4.4.2

JRE 1.8.0

Comment: Please explain your problem

Comment: When I set up Java card home in eclipse to java_card_kit-2_2_1 it gives error 'converter.jar is not compatible, set home location for Java Card Development Kit 2.2.2'

Comment: if you are using WIN7 then please restart your PC because in win 7 environment variable needs restart i dont know why but it happened to me as well.

Comment: @anurag I think the problem is Eclipse-jcde plugin. It is written only for JCDK2.2.2 . So we need a trick to use this plugin with JCDK2.2.1 together.

Comment: anurag i already tried with restart PC. @abraham you are right, it's problem with plugin. your solution sounds cheat ;-) but it works :-). we need to look for other solution as well because it's tricky to replace contents for JCDK for every application.

Comment: You don't need to repeat it again. In the next time, when you open Eclipse, it shows you an alert, but you don't need to do anything! Just do a click on "Cancel" and keep going to develop your applets with JCDK2.2.1 :) Please try it and inform me.

Comment: Did you find any better solution?

Comment: @Abraham, No, I tried with downgrading JDK to check compatibility with JCDK but still not working. For now i m following same procedure as you suggested..will let you know if i find any other solution.

Comment: OK, Thanks. You may want to accept my answer temporary by clicking on the "v" mark near my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, It's a little tricky to solve it. Keep Eclipse open, minimize it and then explore the JCDK direcory in your computer and replace JCDK2.2.2 contents with JCDK2.2.1 contents. Now maximize Eclipse again convert your applets.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problems, are generally caused by version are not compatible. You can replace the JCDK version as the Applet version, can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use [JCIDE](http://www.javacos.com/sdkinfo.php) to develop your Java Card Applet, it is a free IDE for both Java Card 2.2.1 and Java Card 2.2.2. http://www.javacos.com/sdkinfo.php